# customEvents.js and H.removeEvents conflict

Tags: highcharts

When customEvents.js is loaded, H.removeEvent doesn't work.

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var series = chart.series[0];  
    Highcharts.removeEvent(series, "click");
});
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/javiermarquez/dmeuhjnx/)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that the demo which you have shared doesn't show the issue which you wanted to report. What I have done was:

- click on the point to check if the click event works - (the console.log test),
- click on the button to remove the above event,
- step one once again - the event was deleted and no errors have occurred,

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/579g0fst/

Of course, I remembered to uncomment the `customEvent` plugin.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://blacklabel.github.io/custom_events/js/customEvents.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<input id="myButton" type="button" value="Remove series event" />
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian. Thanks for your response. This is weird. I have the same problem using your demo: after clicking in the button for removing the event, the event persists: [link]https://jsfiddle.net/javiermarquez/owrpedug/

Comment: @JavierMárquez that's really weird. On which browser and operating system do you test this demo?

Comment: Sebastian, I have tried in Chrome and Firefox. My OS is macOS Catalina (v. 10.15.4). Cheers!

Comment: @JavierMárquez to be honest, I am not sure what to do in this case. On my device which is macOS Mojave 10.14.16 and the newest Chrome/Firefox everything works fine. I don't know what else could have an impact on this demo.